# Checking if values lie in interval

Tags: python, list

I have a Python list containing integer values. For examples the following list:

```
p = [10,44,55,33]
```

Now I would like to test if at least one of the values in the list falls into a given interval. For example, if we have the interval `[15,30]` it is false because there i no value in p in this interval. If we have the interval `[50,60]` it is true because 55 is in this interval.

I have not only 4 values in my list as in the example above but tens of tousands, so I search the most efficient way to do it. What is the best way?

Comment: Well to start, what is the way *you* tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`any`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/any) with a generator expression:

```
>> any(50 < e < 60 for e in p)
True
```

It will generate only as many checks until the first one is true.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do unless your p is sorted is to scan every element of p and check if it is in your intervall.

You can do this like this:

```
any( interval_low <= i <= interval_high for i in p )
```

Comment: Actually, p is sorted.

Comment: Well that changes everything :-). Now you can do O(log n)

Answer (score 0):

```
p = [10,44,55,33]
i = [10,50]

sol = list(filter(lambda x: x in range(i[0],i[1]+1),p))
# output [10, 44, 33]
```

Answer (score 0):

using list comprehension

```
list1 = [x for x in p if x in range(50,61)]
```